# How do get specific values or a specified value out of a string?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, parsing

I am trying to parse a string that goes as follows:

```
string myString = "Value: 1234567_89042,  Value1: gh,  Value2: New 1";
```

For this, I am trying to get values like these:

```
1234567_89042 
gh
New 1
```

I technically have a solution where I store myString in an array, then I use delimeters to split the string into different segments of an array like so:

```
string[] words = myString.Split(',', ':', ' ', '_');

Console.WriteLine(myString.First());
int count = 0;

foreach (var word in words)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine($"{word}");
    count++;
}
```

I was wondering, would there be a way to not store the string into an array to get those specified values or would I need to keep on parsing it further through an array to get the values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this below code, sure this will work.

```
string myString = "Value: 1234567_89042,  Value1: gh,  Value2: New 1";
string[] str = myString.Split(",");

foreach(string s in str)
{
    string s1 = s.Split(":")[1].Trim();
    Console.WriteLine(s1);
}
```

I tried the above code, it worked perfectly for me!

One more suggestion, I have simplified the above code using LINQ, See below

```
static void Main() 
{
    string myString = "Value: 1234567_89042,  Value1: gh,  Value2: New 1";
    string[] str = myString.Split(",").Select(c => c.Split(":")[1].Trim()).ToArray();

    foreach(string s in str)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}
```

This one also, works fine!

Comment: Thank you it works! Im guessing if i want to parse it even further, like lets say for the value: 1234567_89042, I want to get only 1234567 or only 89042, would I need to put use the same above logic, but put it in a nested for loop?

Comment: Oh damn, I just relaized, if I want to get values such as 1234567 or only 89042, i would just need to take the first element of the array of, which is 1234567_89042, then just keep parsing it further?

Comment: Yes Correct @thesenate42069

Comment: Sorry I have one more question, so I for the output for the values Im getting a space after them, so the output is like ( 1234567_89042), when I am trying to get it like (1234567_89042). Would there be a way to add an extra splitter for " " in the line:        
 (string[] str = myString.Split(",").Select(c => c.Split(":")[1]).ToArray();) ?

Comment: Having been burned by this sort of logic before, one caveat:  Put a Trim() in there.  You're going to get whitespace and someday the amount of white space is liable to change.  The guy running the production system couldn't see why my parser suddenly started puking on everything.  (The program that generated the files started adding a space that wasn't there before.  Completely invisible on the screen.)

Comment: @thesenate42069, To remove the white space, add the .Trim() method into that. Like below, string[] str = myString.Split(",").Select(c => c.Split(":")[1].Trim()).ToArray();